# Ruby. Variable permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem to access to variable in other method in this class. Here is my example:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
 def login
   if params[:login].present? && params[:password].present?
     **@cust_model** = Customers.new
     redirect_to(:action => 'client_dashboard')
   end
 end
 def client_dashboard
  @cust_dashboard = **@cust_model**.dashboard(1)
 end 
end
```

My error is: undefined method dashboard

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. `**@cust_model**` should probably be `@cust_model`

Comment: I think, he tried to make it bold with markdown within the `code` syntax, unknowingly. @PhilippTessenow

Comment: yes...@cust_model should be bold )

Comment: Probably `@cust_model` within `client_dashboard` is `nil`. You could pass a `customer_id` parameter and do a `Customers.find(params[:customer_id])`

Comment: @PhilippTessenow, yeah, but his code is kind of weird. He instantiated @cust_model with a new `Customer`. Even if he wishes to get `@cust_model` in client_dashboard, calling `dashboard` on that non-persisted object is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After redirection from `login`, `@cust_model` will naturally be `nil` in `client_dashboard` action. It can't be inherited from `login` action like this, and that's why `dashboard` is undefined for that `Customer`

Since you have `@cust_model = Customer.new`, you can then sufficiently use `@cust_dashboard = Customer.new.dashboard(1)`, if this is what you intended to (according to your given code).

Cheers.

Comment: so, allways, after redirection I shoul create instance of the class again ?

Comment: In this case, yes. Consider the RESTful structure for CRUD operations, which Rails follow. `new` action instantiates an object, after POST action is triggered from there, it reaches to `create` action. Even there, the object is instantiated again and then saved. 
Same goes for `edit` -> `update` transition, but there, since the object already exists, update and exit expects an id to identify that object instead of instantiating a new one. Hope, it clears. :)